# Javascript Can't Access an Objects Keys Values... They have quotes around them

Tags: javascript, string, variables, object, key

So I need to access the key value "key" in this object:

```
{
  "__v": 0,
  "_id": "5317b71c902ff0080046349f",
  "user": "530ef48599c41200009bad9f",
  "email": "asdfa@sdgdf.com",
  "btcId": "9HjBb9eUhyXMKuVxSrTSkg",
  "name": "Bitcoin Payments",
  "dlFile": "a43ca076-4802-4cca-9648-82b2569ffc60.docx",
  "key": "3518d5ce-badf-495c-a08f-dc28bb6d8a64",
  "created": "2014-03-05T23:45:32.480Z"
}
```

but this code doesn't work:

```
console.log(body.key) -> Undefined
console.log(body['key'] -> undefined
console.log(body['"key"'] -> undefined
```

body is where the object is stored.

I think it has something to do with the key's being strings? or having the "" around them?
However I'm not creating the body variable so I can't control this...

Any ideas on how to make it work?

Comment: [The first and second should work](http://jsfiddle.net/RBgqd/), unless `body` isn't what you think it is. Try `console.log(body)` to see what is really is.

Comment: What do you mean they have quotes, do you have a string or an object.

Comment: @gbachik Do you have `var body = {
  "__v": 0,
  "_id": "5317b71c902ff0080046349f",
  "user": "530ef48599c41200009bad9f",
  "email": "asdfa@sdgdf.com",
  "btcId": "9HjBb9eUhyXMKuVxSrTSkg",
  "name": "Bitcoin Payments",
  "dlFile": "a43ca076-4802-4cca-9648-82b2569ffc60.docx",
  "key": "3518d5ce-badf-495c-a08f-dc28bb6d8a64",
  "created": "2014-03-05T23:45:32.480Z"
}`?

Comment: Looks like you have JSON data, not a JS object. If so, you should `JSON.parse()` it.

Comment: To verify, do this `console.log(typeof body);`. If it's JSON data, you'll get `"string"`.

Comment: Facepalm! It was a JSON object thats why! Thanks guys <3

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`However I'm not creating the body variable so I can't control this...`

This sounds like a `GET` request, so if it's JSON data, parse it with `JSON.parse`:

```
console.log(JSON.parse(body).key)
```

Comment: Yeh it worked! Didn't realize it was JSON data. Thanks!